# HTML 5 History API with PopState and AJAX keeps reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-history

I'm currently loading data onto the page via Ajax updating the url via `pushState`, no errors. And `popstate` returns the full object into the console — for viewing purposes.

I'm at the point where the forward and back buttons work partially, meaning, sometimes it will reshow the content when the url changes, but most of the time it simple reloads the page which is stopping the smooth flow of the application.

Been working endless trying to get things to work, without success :(

I just can't figure out why the page keeps reloading and reverting back to the first instance.

I think it might have something to do with the state being or not being set on first viewing of the page.

My code below, which fires an Ajax request on loading then updates the pages content when the dropdown is changed by the user.

```
$(function() {
"use strict";
var $results  = $('#results');

    // First dataset when page loads
    (function(){
      var x = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/';
      var swFirstCall = $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: x,
        async: false
      });
      swFirstCall.done(function(data) {
        var template = $('#results_tpl').html();
        var html = Mustache.render(template, data);
        $results.html(html);
      });
    })();

    // New dataset based on selected category
    $(document).on('change', '#categories', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var category = this.value; // get selected value
      var x = 'https://swapi.co/api/' + category + '/';
      var swChangeCall = $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: x,
        async: false
      });
      swChangeCall.done(function(data) {
        var template = $('#results_tpl').html();
        var html = Mustache.render(template, data);
        $('#results').html(html);
        console.log("Category: " + category);

        window.history.pushState(
            // data
            // title
            // url
            category,
            category,
            window.location.pathname + '?page=' + category
            );
      });
    });
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
          window.location.href = window.location.href;
          console.log(event);
          return(event);
    });
});
```

Any help much appreciated. I've searched Stackoverflow, and many other resources though can't understand.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBBPov?editors=0010) if it helps viewing code.

Thanks, Barry

Comment: Never ever use `async: false` in ajax...it is a horrible practice and is deprecated by browser vendors. There never has been any good reason to ever need it. You should be seeing warnings about that deprecation in your browser console

Comment: I removed `async: false` and the error has gone :)
`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.`
I realized `.done` and `.then` can be used in its place. The reason behind this was because in some instances, I need the `id` of a particular item from the first ajax request, so that the second ajax request would work.

Comment: In that case make second request after first completes

Comment: Would that be accomplished by using `.done` or `.then` as mentioned above @charlietfl?

Comment: Yes it would....

Comment: Is this a bad thing? I thought this was classed as `chaining` and used a lot in the JS world.

Comment: is what a bad thing? Not clear what you are asking

Comment: I thought by using `async: false`, `.done` or `.then` we are executing our code `synchronously` — slowing the application down. Where most people build applications so everything is `asynchronously`. Or maybe its ok for small portions? Just trying to understand and follow best practices, thanks.

Comment: for things like ajax that are asynchronous by nature you have to learn how to work with them asynchronously. `then()` is a promise callback and promises are asynchronous. Forget that `async:false` even exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is store the `data` and `category` variables in your history state object when you `pushState`.  Later, you will then pull that state out when you trigger a `popstate` event (user goes back and forward).  With the values you get out of the `popstate` event, you will then need to rerender the page.  I made changes to your `pushState` function and your `popstate` handler to show how this can be done.  Finally, you will want to follow the advice in one of the comments about removing the `async: false` option in your ajax call - there's no reason you need to hold up the rest of your script execution like this.

EDIT:  Forgot to mention that you'll want to initialize your state object on first page load.  Use the `replaceState` method to do this as you don't want to create another history entry.  Rather, you want to modify the current history entry to include the `category` and `data` you would want to return to when the user goes back to the initial page.  See below for your `swFirstCall.done` method with the `replaceState` call included.

```
// ...

swFirstCall.done(function(data) {
  var template = $('#results_tpl').html();
  var html = Mustache.render(template, data);
  $results.html(html);
// initialize history state object
  window.history.replaceState(
    { category: 'Select Category', data  },
    null,
    '',
  );

// ...

window.history.pushState(
  // data
  // title
  // url
  { category, data },
  category,
  window.location.pathname + '?page=' + category
);

// ...

window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  window.location.pathname + '?page=' + event.state.category;
  var template = $('#results_tpl').html();
  var html = Mustache.render(template, event.state.data);
  $('#results').html(html);
  $('#categories').val(event.state.category);
});

// ..
```

Comment: Excellent :) Things are taking shape @Kal, working good cheers. One small issue which I've found. When I try and go back to the first page, the original content is not shown and I see the error _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of null_

Comment: @computerbarry good catch.  let me add an edit to my original answer to get that fixed.

Comment: Perfect! You forgot to remove the last comma @Kal `'',` — fixed once I removed it. And thanks again, really helped with this. I've removed the edit I made to the original question. I'll see if I can build something myself for the extra Ajax requests.